# How to prevent connection time out while publishing to Azure (during Updating file step)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, connection-timeout, azure-deployment

I am Publishing my Azure web app from Visual Studio 2017 on a slow internet connection (< 1.5Mbps upload speed -- Telstra in Australia).

I have been watching the ping replies while doing Publish. Whenever I get to a certain point in the Publish process -- after "Adding ACLs for path" and during "Updating file.. Project.dll" -- the internet connection will time out (ping will go "Request timed out"). Once I cancel the Web Publish Activity, the ping reply comes back. I have tried this multiple times with the exact same result.

How do I prevent the "Updating file" step of the Publish from causing the internet connection to time out?

(Please do not suggest getting a faster connection -- that will work but that option is not available to me for the next 2 weeks)

Comment: I understand that the ping shows "Request timed out". But, does the publishing process reach the end? or are you getting also an error from Visual Studio?  However, AFAIK there is no way to reduce upload bandwidth used by Visual Studio.

Comment: No VS does not reach the end and also times out. "Publish has encountered an error. Build failed. Check the Output window for more details." I know this is due to a timeout because when I try it on a faster connection, it doesn't hit this error. Is there a setting for VS to wait a bit longer before timeout?